# PHP array will not assing key values

Tags: php

UPDATE: Here's the full controller method:

```
protected $game = [];

private function stageAction($type, $actions)
{
    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        Log::info('STAGE ACTION started with $type= '.$type.' *********************');
    }

    $message                    = [];
    $this->game['sys_msg']      = [];
    $this->game['stage_action'] = [];

    switch ($type) {

        case 'attack_end':
            $message['action']  = 'ignore';
            $message['message'] = '<b>'.active_player()['nickname'].'</b> ends their attack.';
            $this->game['sys_msg'] = $message;
            break;

        case ......
            break;

        default:
    }

    // If it is an "ignored" message then send it now
    if ($this->game['sys_msg']['action'] == 'ignore') {
        $this->broadcastSysMsg();
    }

    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        Log::info('SYS MSG - '.print_r($this->game['sys_msg'], true));
    }
```

---

In my Laravel controller I have a global property like this:

```
protected $game = [];
```

In one of the methods, I add a key to it like this:

```
$this->game['sys_msg'] = [];
```

Then I add values to it like this:

```
$message['action']  = 'ignore';
$message['message'] = 'My message is blah blah blah...';
$this->game['sys_msg'] = $message;
```

Further down in the code I inspect it by logging its output like this:

```
Log::info('SYS MSG - '.print_r($this->game['sys_msg'], true));
```

But I get this:

```
[]
```

I want to assign an array of objects to this value. Why is this not working yet not failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues, you have not iniaizlied `$message`, you have just started setting values in it. Either initiallize it, or better yet, just assign it directly as this will be faster.

```
$message = [
  'action'  => 'ignore',
  'message' => 'My message is blah blah blah...'
];
```

You could also go one step further and assign it directly to the `game` member:

```
$this->game['sys_msg'] = [
  'action'  => 'ignore',
  'message' => 'My message is blah blah blah...'
];
```

As for your failure to see the updated value, it could be caused by numerous things, please post a full code example.

Edit:

After seeing your code example a few more suggestions.

Do not use an array like you are, create a class for the `sys_msg`, this way you do not risk a typo such as `aCtion` cusing a strange bug. You can also ensure it is initialized to a known state. For example:

```
class SysMsg
{
  const ACTION_IGNORE  = 0;
  const ACTION_PROCESS = 1;

  protected $action;
  protected $message;

  public function __construct($action = self::ACTION_IGNORE, $message = null)
  {
    $this->action  = $action;
    $this->message = $message;
  }

  public function getAction () { return $this->action; }
  public function getMessage() { return $this->message; }
}

class SysMsg_AttackEnd extends SysMsg
{
  protected $player;

  public function __construct($player)
  {
    parent::__construct(SysMsg::ACTION_IGNORE, "");
    $this->player = $player;
  }

  public function getMessage()
  {
    return '<b>' . $this->player['nickname'] . '</b> ends their attack.';
  }
}


private function stageAction($type, $actions)
{
  switch($type)
  {
    case 'attack_end':
      $msg = new SysMsg_AttackEnd(active_player());
      break;        
  }

  if (isset($msg) && $msg->getAction() == SysMsg::ACTION_IGNORE)
  {
    $this->game['sys_msg'] = $msg;
    $this->broadcastSysMsg();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can i know, this code

```
$this->game['sys_msg'] = [];
```

this is before or after this line ?

```
$message['action']  = 'ignore';
$message['message'] = 'My message is blah blah blah...';
$this->game['sys_msg'] = $message;
```